# Submitting form info to Model from view, then invoking the model to run

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am trying to submit info from a form in my view, that passes the submitted info :hashtag into the model and then runs the model with that info.  But it seems thats my model just runs with the words "hashtag" instead of the form info.  I believe it is close.  I just can't figure out where to go next.

**home.html.erb**

```
  <div class="row">
      <div class="span6 offset2">

                <%= form_for :hashtag do |f| %>
                <div class="input-prepend input-append">
                <span class="add-on swag">#</span>

                <%= f.text_field :hashtag , class: "span3 inverse", id:"appendedPrependedInput" %>

                <%= f.submit "Swag!", class: "btn btn-inverse" %>
                <% end %>

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="span4">
        <div id="hashtags">
            <% @random_hashtags.each do |hashtag| %>
            <blockquote><%= hashtag.content %></blockquote>
            <div class="from">&mdash; @<%= hashtag.screen_name %></div>
        <% end %>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**hashtag.rb**

```
class Hashtag < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content, :profile_image, :screen_name, :tweet_date, :tweet_id

  def self.pull_hashtag
  Twitter.search("%#{hashtag}").results.map do |tweet|
    unless exists?(tweet_id: tweet.id)
        create!(
            tweet_id: tweet.id,
            content: tweet.text,
            profile_image: tweet.profile_image_url,
            screen_name: tweet.from_user,
            tweet_date: tweet.created_at
            )   
        end     
    end
  end
end
```

**hashtags_controller**

```
    class HashtagsController < ApplicationController

    def home 
        @random_hashtags = Hashtag.order("RANDOM()").limit(4)
    end

    def create
        @hashtag = Hashtag.pull_hashtag(params[:search])
    end         
end
```

**Updated code that I am currently using now as I was not posting anything to the model**

**It is going though on submit but it seems nothing from there.**

Update 2,

I am trying to post the information to the database, by taking the info from the form, running a Twitter.search on it and creating the results in my database.

Comment: Are there more methods (like create) in your hashtags_controller? What do the relevant routes look like?

Comment: That is the complete hashtags_controller file.  Nothing really custom in the routes,   root :to => "hashtags#home"

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you are trying to achieve, but if you send that form it should include the key `"hashtag" => { "hashtag" => <what you filled in> }` in params I believe.

Comment: Trying to get  def self.pull_hashtag to run with the results from the submit form

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to replace with this?

```
form_for @hashtag, :url => :action => 'home'
```

my guess is that the action needs to be specified.

Comment: Gives all sorts of errors `: syntax error, unexpected tASSOC, expecting keyword_end
...or @hashtag, :url => :action => 'home' do |f| @output_buffer...
...                               ^`

Comment: should be `form_for @hashtag, :url => { :action => 'home' }` in that case (don't know if that is the solution though)

Comment: Gives error `undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class
`

Comment: ...and if `@hashtag` has a value, it's Railish to use `:hashtag`.

Comment: Not really sure what you are saying here

Comment: I couldn't edit my first comment (to old) when I noticed the second thing. I meant this: if you should use this suggestion it would be like `form_for :hashtag, :url => { :action => 'home' }` because if @hashtag has a value it will use that, and that is the preferred syntax, and if @hashtag is nil it will not give an error, only using "hashtag" for the names in the generated html. Summary: I was only trying to correct this suggestion a bit :) and not saying that it will help.